# Encrypt a string using OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, encryption

I have a problem with encrypting a string.
I have the command to encrypt a file using OpenSSL.
But I wanted to know the encrypt the string not the File.
The command for encrypting a file is:

```
system("openssl des3 -e -nosalt -in %s -out  %s -k %s > /tmp/sys; cat /tmp/sys", src, dest, key);
```

where src and dest are the two file names.
what are the options available with OPEN SSL.
In above in and out are options for encrypting a text file.
I need the option to encrypting character array variable.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out on another question (by someone who dug through the code more than I did):

https://opensource.conformal.com/viewgit/?a=viewblob&p=cyphertite&h=899259f8ba145c11087088ec83153db524031800&hb=6782c6839d847fbed0aed8c55917e78b5684110f&f=cyphertite/ct_crypto.c

has the code you need to use OpenSSL natively to perform encryption/decryption in your app.

Happy hacking!